# Compound index with three keys, what happens if I query skipping the middle one?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance, compound-index

With PostgreSQL, I want to use a compound index on three columns `A, B, C`. `B` is the `created_at` datetime, and occasionally I might query without `B`.

What happens if I compound index on `(A, B, C)` but then query with conditions on `A` and `C`, but not `B`? (That is, `A` and `C` but want it over all time, not just some specific time range?)

Is Postgres smart enough to still use the `(A, B, C)` compound index but just skip B?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres can use non-leading columns in a [multicolumn B-tree index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html), but in a far less efficient mode.

If the first column is very selective (only few rows per `A`) then you will hardly notice a difference in performance since either access method is cheap. The performance hit grows with the number of rows per `A`.

For the case you describe I suggest to create the index on **`(A, C, B)`** or `(C, A, B)`. Just make sure `B` comes last. Or drop `B` from the index altogether. Or create another index for use cases with `B`. This way you get best performance for queries on `(A, B, C)` and on `(A, C)` alike.

Unlike the sequence of columns in the index, the sequence of predicates in the query does not matter.

We have discussed this in great detail on dba.SE:

- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684)

Note that it does ***not*** matter whether you lead with `A, C` or `C, A` for the case at hand:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)

There are also some other considerations, but your question does not have all the relevant details.

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

I did a quick check by doing an EXPLAIN of a query that had a condition for the first and third column of an index. It did output that it would do a Bitmap Index Scan on that index and mentioned both the first and the third column in the index condition.

(Tested on 9.3.5)

Comment: Could you post that explain plan please?