# postgres: search by varchar which is enum in java

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a table which I query on the `varchar` column. It can be one of the very few values possible (it's a simple java enum).

The SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   activation 
WHERE  registration = '1312313'
       AND status = 'WORKING';
```

Here I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE` https://explain.depesz.com/s/Whuq, as it seems the problem is in the filtering by status. There is an index on the `registration` column.

Would it be reasonable to add an index on the `status` column or it's overkill here? If yes, how could I optimize the given query?

Answer (score 1):

For this query, you want a *compound* index on the columns that appear in the `where`  clause. It is usually a good idea to put the most restrictive criteria first (here, I understand this is `registration`):

```
create index activation_idx on activation(registration, status);
```

If you always filter on the same `status` value, then [a partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) might be at least as efficient, and less expensive:

```
create index activation_idx_partial 
    on activation(registration) 
    where status = 'WORKING';
```

Comment: Firstly, never knew about the partial index, but I filter on the few `status` value.

Secondly, it really depends on the data on which criteria are more restrictive. It worked well when the initial filtering by `registration` returned just a few records, but it turned out that it's not always so, that's why I puzzled with it in the first place.

So, I need a query which is not dependable on the order of predicates. Probably the compound index will be a solution. Do I need to remove my old `registration` only index? Or it's ok to have them both?

Comment: @fasth: from technical perspective having both indexes is OK (Postgres will pick the one it prefers). But bottom line, there is no point keeping an index that is not used (it costs storage and incurs more work for the database on DML statements) - so, unless you have another query that uses the index, just drop it.

Comment: @GBM: based on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217030/compound-index-with-three-keys-what-happens-if-i-query-skipping-the-middle-one, the efficiency won't be hit badly if `registration` filtering is very selective and I will use this compound index in other places instead of plain one (`create index activation_reg on activation(registration)`)?